# Share button on twitter not working properly

Tags: php, html, twitter

I want to add twitter button on my website. 
The code I am using is:

```
echo"<iframe src='https://www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fconnecting-youth.org%2Fsingle_news.php%3Fsubmit%3D".$lastnum."&layout=button_count&size=small&mobile_iframe=true&width=69&height=20&appId' width='69' height='20' style='border:none;overflow:hidden' scrolling='no' frameborder='0' allowTransparency='true'></iframe>
    <a style='margin-left:10px;' class='twitter-share-button'  href='https://twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fconnecting-youth.org%2Fsingle_news.php%3Fsubmit%3D".$lastnum."'  data-size='large'>Tweet</a>
    ";
```

The problem is that on twitter it appears as text not as a post. 
For example [image]

The way I want it to appear is: 
[image]

It works fine when I add another URL.

Comment: If that is the **exact** code that you are using, then you need to echo the php variable in order to include it in the url:  `<a class='twitter-share-button'  href='https://twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fconnecting-youth.org%2Fsingle_news.php%3Fsubmit%3D<?php echo $lastnum; ?>'  data-size='large'>Tweet</a>`  Otherwise, could you please include the entire line of code that you are using?  Also, sample output for the non-working and working links would be very helpful.

Comment: @mtr.web I included the entire line of code. In any case the link is pasted correctly on twitter but it doesn't appear as ti should (output shown on the captures included in the question)

Answer (score 0):

Try shortening it useing for example https://bitly.com